# What is the difference between vector of features (x) and feature space (X)?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

What is the difference between vector (x) of features and feature space (X)? I always though that big X was ALL the features and little x was about a specific feature.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The big $\mathcal X$ is the space of all possible values the features, and the little $x$ is a point in that space.

This is no different from saying $x\in\mathbb R^n$, though $\mathcal X$ is more general (could have categorical features, for instance).

$\mathcal X = \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \times \{\text{dog}, \text{cat}, \text{horse}\}$ is a perfectly acceptable $\mathcal X$ and would represent two features that can take any real number and a third feature that is categorical (with levels of $\text{dog}$, $\text{cat}$, and $\text{horse}$).

(One might argue that the feature space should encode the categorical feature in $0$s and $1$s (e.g., one-hot encoding categories), though that is a separate issue.)

Comment: But according to the University Slight I posted above, it says that little "x is a vector of features (realizations) rather than a single value". The way I understand it is if the 8th row for example has X8,1 = 8 and X8, 2 = 1 that means that X8 = (8,2). Where i is the i th data point in the training set and d is the dimension of the feature vector. So if little x is a vector of features, what does mean big X (the feature space)?

Comment: What tips me off is that the $y$ is indexed by $i$, even though $y$ does not have multiple components. This mean that $i$ refers to the observation number in $x$, not the feature number.

Comment: Yeah, it refers to the observation number in x and d refers to the feature number. So if I understood well, little x refers to the entire row or index or observation number for all the feature number: for example if i = 8th observation number, that means that for all features we will take only the 8th observation number. That will be our feature vector or little x. Whereas big X refers to all points of the dataset, which mean that it includes all observation number (i) and all feature number (d). Is it correct?

Comment: That's close, but $\mathcal X$ means the entire feature space, so all *possible* combinations of features, not just the observed combinations of features. $\mathcal X = \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \times \{\text{dog}, \text{cat}, \text{horse}\}$ is an example of $\mathcal X$, not $\mathcal X = \{(1, -2, dog), (-2, 4, cat), (10, -1000, horse)\}$ (unless you really do want to restrict $\mathcal X$ to be just those).

Comment: Ok that's clear for the big X. Thanks. Could you please confirm that my definition of the little x is correct from my last comment?

Comment: Little $x$ is some unspecified point in the big $\mathcal X$ space, same as $a\in\mathbb R^n$ is some unspecified point in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134827/discussion-between-python-guy-and-dave).